# Deformación de Triangulo CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer, es que sobre una pantalla(div) donde almaceno todos los objetos(botones y otros elementos...) tenga una transición.
Esta transición va a tener dos "cortinas" que realmente son 2 triángulos hechos con un div y estilo bottom. Cuando realice la deformación de la primera cortina izquierda, salió muy bien, no tenía errores, pero cuando quise invertirla y ponerla como cortina derecha con el método "transform: rotate()", esta se cambiaba de posición.

Aquí dejo unos ejemplos de lo que avance y de como quisiera que se vea. Me gustaría que me ayudasen y me digan si es posible realizar lo que deseo.

#1 Probando la cortina izquierda

```js
const btnOpenWindow = document.getElementById("openWin");
const tranLeft = document.getElementById("transitionLeft");
const tranRight = document.getElementById("transitionRight");

// Add Event on click button
btnOpenWindow.addEventListener("click",function(){
    let transition = {
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        loop: 0,
        dateLoop: "",
    }    
    
    transition.dateLoop = setInterval(windowOpenClose, 5);

    function windowOpenClose(){
        tranLeft.style.borderBottom = `${transition.left}px solid transparent`;
        // tranRight.style.borderBottom = `${transition.left}px solid transparent`;    
        if(transition.loop == 0){
            transition.left += 4;
        }
        if(transition.loop == 1){
            transition.left -= 4;
        }
        if(transition.loop == 0 && transition.left == 600){
            transition.loop = 1;
        }
        if(transition.loop == 1 && transition.left == -1){
            transition.loop = 0;        
            transition.left = 0;
            transition.right = 0;
            clearInterval(transition.dateLoop);
        }
    
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        #box{
            background-color: palevioletred;
            width: 800px;
            height: 600px;
        }
        #transitionLeft{
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-left: 800px solid black;
            border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
            position: absolute;
        }
        #transitionRight{
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-left: 800px solid black;
            border-bottom: 600px solid transparent;
            transform: rotate(180deg);
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="box">
        <div id="transition">
            <div id="transitionLeft"></div>
            <div id="transitionRight"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button id="openWin">Open</button>
   
</body>
</html>
```

#2 Probando la cortina derecha

```js
const btnOpenWindow = document.getElementById("openWin");
const tranLeft = document.getElementById("transitionLeft");
const tranRight = document.getElementById("transitionRight");

// Add Event on click button
btnOpenWindow.addEventListener("click",function(){
    let transition = {
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        loop: 0,
        dateLoop: "",
    }    
    
    transition.dateLoop = setInterval(windowOpenClose, 5);

    function windowOpenClose(){
        tranLeft.style.borderBottom = `${transition.left}px solid transparent`;
        tranRight.style.borderBottom = `${transition.left}px solid transparent`;    
        if(transition.loop == 0){
            transition.left += 4;
        }
        if(transition.loop == 1){
            transition.left -= 4;
        }
        if(transition.loop == 0 && transition.left == 600){
            transition.loop = 1;
        }
        if(transition.loop == 1 && transition.left == -1){
            transition.loop = 0;        
            transition.left = 0;
            transition.right = 0;
            clearInterval(transition.dateLoop);
        }
    
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        #box{
            background-color: palevioletred;
            width: 800px;
            height: 600px;
        }
        #transitionLeft{
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-left: 800px solid black;
            border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
            position: absolute;
        }
        #transitionRight{
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-left: 800px solid yellow;
            border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
            transform: rotate(180deg);
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="box">
        <div id="transition">
            <div id="transitionLeft"></div>
            <div id="transitionRight"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button id="openWin">Open</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```

#3 Como me gustaria que sea el efecto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es la manera en la que cambia el tamaño la cortina derecha, a como lo tienes si bien el tamaño crece lo hace desde la parte superior del elemento, y tu necesitas que siempre crezca desde abajo.

Para hacer esto puedes usar la propiedad `bottom:0` (para anclar la segunda cortina a la parte inferior) y para que esto funcione también debes de asignar a su padre con la propiedad de `position:relative`.

```js
const btnOpenWindow = document.getElementById("openWin");
const tranLeft = document.getElementById("transitionLeft");
const tranRight = document.getElementById("transitionRight");

// Add Event on click button
btnOpenWindow.addEventListener("click",function(){
    let transition = {
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        loop: 0,
        dateLoop: "",
    }    
    
    transition.dateLoop = setInterval(windowOpenClose, 5);

    function windowOpenClose(){
        tranLeft.style.borderBottom = `${transition.left}px solid transparent`;
        tranRight.style.borderBottom = `${transition.left}px solid transparent`;    
        if(transition.loop == 0){
            transition.left += 4;
        }
        if(transition.loop == 1){
            transition.left -= 4;
        }
        if(transition.loop == 0 && transition.left == 600){
            transition.loop = 1;
        }
        if(transition.loop == 1 && transition.left == -1){
            transition.loop = 0;        
            transition.left = 0;
            transition.right = 0;
            clearInterval(transition.dateLoop);
        }
    
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        #box{
            background-color: palevioletred;
            width: 800px;
            height: 600px;
            position:relative;
        }
        #transitionLeft{
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-left: 800px solid black;
            border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
            position: absolute;
        }
        #transitionRight{
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            bottom:0;
            border-left: 800px solid yellow;
            border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
            transform: rotate(180deg);
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="box">
        <div id="transition">
            <div id="transitionLeft"></div>
            <div id="transitionRight"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button id="openWin">Open</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```